# Left and right eigenspaces of the product of Gramians

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, eigenvalues, matrix-equations

I solve the Lyapunov equations :

$$ A W_C E^T + E W_C A^T + B B^T = 0 $$
$$ A^T W_O E^T + E W_O A + C^T C = 0 $$

to obtain $ W_C $ and $W_O$. My aim is to get the left and right eigenspaces of $W_C W_O$. This is basically for model order reduction through balanced truncation.

Currently I am explicitly generating $W_C$ and $W_O$, and calculating the `schur` decomposition as

```
W_c = lyap(A,B*B',[],E);
W_o = lyap(A',C'*C,[],E);
W_j = W_c*W_o;
[Vs,Ts] = schur(W_j);
Vst = Vs';
V_lk = Vst(:,1:ordr);
V_rk = Vs(:,1:ordr);
```

How can I optimize the process of calculating the dominant eigenspaces? Links to some theory behind any techniques will be very helpful.

Additional Information : I am aware of ADI, and read quite a few of the papers based on it. However, there are 2 problems with it being applicable to my case.

1. My original system is dense, a product of another model reduction. Isn't ADI specific to Sparse systems?
2. My grammians will NOT be positive definite, because its not fully controllable/observable. They are in-fact indefinite (negative and positive) eigenvalues. Therefore Cholesky factor is not applicable. Is there a different factorization I could use with ADI?

Comment: To clarify, by "dominant" you mean the eigenvalues of largest magnitude? And you only want a few of the biggest ones, for which computing the Schur decomposition is overkill?

Comment: Yes. To be exact, I want to obtain the vectors representing spaces spanned by the eigenvectors corresponding to some `k` largest eigenvalues. If not Schur, how best? Can you point me to some smarter methods? Thanks.

Comment: How large are your systems? (both the ones before and after the model reduction)

Comment: Re your additional information: (1) ADI does not necessarily assume "sparse", but only "can solve shifted linear systems fast", although for large-scale matrices the two are often synonyms. If you already applied model reduction, then hopefully your system is already small enough to go with dense methods as you did in the code snippet. (2) I might be wrong, but on the top of my head I think that ADI works also if the Gramians are only semidefinite. The method will simply ignore the non-controllable/observable subspaces, and yield $X=VV^T$ factorizations (which are not Cholesky) nevertheless.

Comment: Before Reduction ~200, after Reduction ~40-80. Though this is aimed more towards a proof of concept of a certain idea. The numbers themselves certainly aren't deserving of so much optimization.

Comment: (1) makes a lot of sense. But (2) is interesting if it can be shown theoretically. I also seem to have negative eigenvalues, which would make the Grammians indefinite rather than semidefinite, but I will confirm.

Comment: The input to this reduction is a system originally of order ~10k, reduced to 200 by a [different method](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/prima-gives-an-unstable-result).

Comment: Regarding (2) @FedericoPoloni is right. Semi-definiteness is even welcomed in ADI, as one looks for low-rank factors. However, I am not sure about indefiniteness. Peter Benner does not give conditions for convergence but refers the reader to earlier papers by Wachspress on ADI.

Comment: Maybe I am making a silly mistake, but this should be a proof that ADI works also if the Gramian is semidefinite: (1) use Kalman decomposition $A=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12}\\\\ 0 & A_{22}\end{bmatrix}$, $B=\begin{bmatrix}B_1\\\\0\end{bmatrix}$; (2) notice that the second block never gets altered, so you could as well work on $(A_{11}, B_1)$ (3) This pair is controllable, so ADI works. As for indefinite, I don't know.

Comment: @Jan : I have updated the question. I checked, my grammians are indefinite, both +ve and -ve eigenvalues.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni ditto.

Answer (score 5):

One of the best-performing methods for solving large-scale Lyapunov equations is ADI. It is an iterative algorithm that returns an approximate low-rank decomposition $X \approx VV^T$ of the solution $X$. In this case, you can work with this decomposition of both Gramians to reduce the eigenproblem to a smaller one.

I suggest you to start approaching this algorithm by reading the paper *Numerical solution of large-scale Lyapunov equations, Riccati equations, and linear-quadratic optimal control problems*, by Benner, Li and Penzl, the user manual for the Matlab library [Lyapack](http://www.tu-chemnitz.de/sfb393/lyapack/), or one of the many talks on the webpage of [Peter Benner](http://www.mpi-magdeburg.mpg.de/mpcsc/benner/talks.php?lang=en).

Comment: @FredericoPoloni: Thanks, I have added more info to the question.

Comment: Can you join http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9436/lyapunov ? I have a few questions which would be difficult to ask in this format.

Answer (score 0):

In a 2012 [paper](https://www.math.temple.edu/~szyld/reports/report_Riccati.rev.pdf), Simoncini, Szyld and Monsalve review several techniques for solving large scale Riccati equations but mainly focus on a Galerkin projection approach to Lyapunov equations.

However, as a basic assumption they have $A$ always Hurwitz, what would render the Gramians definite (if E is positive definite).